# removing file attributes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How can I go about removing a file attribute that I applied to a file. In my particular circumstance i've applied the "do not backup" attributed added in 5.0.1 and I now want to remove that attribut does anybody know how I can achieve this

Comment: developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html

Tells you how to apply it but not how to remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm I figured it out you simply just set the value = 0. Over looked that.